# Laravel's React Breeze ,Always can't run : npm run dev

Tags: npm, npm-install, vite, laravel-breeze, react-laravel

### The Vite doesn't work

Os:CentOs7
Laravel: 9.26.1
node: v16.17.0
npm: 8.15.0

I would like use new Laravel Project with React.js.
And try the plug-in Breeze for Authentication

I use the command

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel new-project
php artisan breeze:install
php artisan breeze:install react
npm install
npm run dev
```

At first all command successful complete , but when i use

```
npm run dev
```

the server told me

```
/tmp/dev-xxxxxx.sh: line 1: vite: command not found
```

and i try the solution
https://github.com/vitejs/vite/discussions/5432

and
https://github.com/vitejs/vite/issues/1215

that's all not work for me

this is package.json

```
{
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "vite",
        "build": "vite build"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@headlessui/react": "^1.4.2",
        "@inertiajs/inertia": "^0.11.0",
        "@inertiajs/inertia-react": "^0.8.0",
        "@inertiajs/progress": "^0.2.6",
        "@tailwindcss/forms": "^0.5.2",
        "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^2.0.0",
        "alpinejs": "^3.4.2",
        "autoprefixer": "^10.4.2",
        "axios": "^0.27",
        "laravel-vite-plugin": "^0.5.0",
        "lodash": "^4.17.19",
        "postcss": "^8.4.6",
        "react": "^17.0.2",
        "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
        "tailwindcss": "^3.1.0"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "vite": "^3.0.9"
    }
}
```

How should I do to resolve this question？

Answer (score 0):

I find the question
i type before npm install

```
npm config set bin-links false
```

because CentOs7 have sym link error(bin-link to my laptop)
that can not install complete

---

so i should set bin-links to true
and
npm install vite

it's would solve the problem